# Selectable categories and products in magento admin

Tags: magento

**Goal**

---

I am upgrading a custom in-house module for magento EE.  The module groups clients together and has special rules that can be applied to the group or individuals of the group. I need to add an extra tab that allows, on a per group basis, to select items and/or categories.  When they are selected people within this group will not be allowed to see those categories or products.

**What I have**

---

I have the the tab created and I know what I need to do on the front-end to achieve my goals.  The issue is creating the selector. I have played with it for a couple hours and made no real headway as of yet. I have only been doing magento development for the past 5 weeks, so I am very new to this framework.

**What I need help with**

---

I would like to select the categories and items in the same fashion as when you go to Catalog->Categories->Manage Categories. The left column has a tiered list. I would like to have one like this but with check boxes for selection. When looking at Promotions->shopping cart rules->actions(tab), select a rule, choose the actions tab. In the second fieldset, if you add a new rule 'category' and then select the icon for the tiered tree that is exactly what I want. Same idea for products, its okay if the look is different.  Just need to be able to do it both ways.

I need to be able to store the selected values, and retrieve them (easy once I know how to store them).

Please provide any code, guidance, or links to tutorials which are in the ball park. It would be much appreciated. I'm sure the generic option of being able to select things in this manner would be helpful to all.

Comment: Magento admin panel categories and promotions rely very heavily on prototype. Replicating them is not so easily but creating a custom table with an admin interface to do CRUD is fairly straightforward.  http://inchoo.net/magento/getting-started-with-building-admin-module-in-magento/ and http://inchoo.net/magento/getting-started-with-magento-orm-setting-up-the-model/

Comment: Thank you for your input, @VladimirRamik. I may have to go that route.  Was hoping to do something a little more visually pleasing.  At this point what ever it takes to get the job done =)  I am still open to options or ideas from all.